# structure in getMetadata activity for csv file dataset show string datatypes for integer column in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to do validation as first step before proceeding further in pipeline execute.
I am fetching metadata activity for my dataset and then checking it against a predefined schema in if condition.
Metadata for csv files show column type string even for integer which is breaking the validation.

Comment: All the data type in CSV file is string. Only during copy active, data factory will auto convert the data to a suitable data type according the data string.

Comment: You can use the columnCount to verify the schema. If the source data type can not convert to Sink dataset's, the pipeline will failed and you get the error message like "can not convert to xx data type".

Comment: i need to validate the data types as well before going ahead in pipeline execution, i checked with json files but it doesn't have support for structure field list in getMetadata activity

Comment: did you try expression:`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure` to get the list?

Comment: yes for csv files, it gives all column names and type but type is string even for integer columns and in json file, the structure field list not supported

Comment: Yeah, Get Metadata doesn't support it, all the data type is considered as string.  Per my experience, the structure only works well for database. Maybe you could ask Azure Support for more details. Or post a new Data Factory feedback here:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory

Comment: If you need, I can do a summary and post an answer.

Comment: I have posted a question on microsoft forums, actually in one of the example of getMetadata activity output, they have shown int data type for one the columns of csv file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/44635/structure-in-getmetadata-activity-for-csv-file-dat.html

Comment: Thanks @PANKAJ LOHANI, but the answer seams not works.

Comment: Hello @PANKAJ LOHANI, I make a summary and post it as answer. I think that is by-design problem, even the Microsoft MSFT don't know the workaround. Please follow my suggestions.  If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: If you have any other concerns, please let us know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get Metadata doesn't support it, all the data type is considered as string in csv files.

You have posted a question on Microsoft forums here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/44635/structure-in-getmetadata-activity-for-csv-file-dat.html, but Microsoft MSFT confirmed that: Using getMetadata on a csv file will give all strings.

The link he provided doesn't work for the column type.

I think that's a by-design problem and has no workaround now. And per my experience, the structure only works well for database.

The best way for you it that ask [Azure Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for more details. Or post a new Data Factory feedback here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory. Hope the Data Factory Product team will see it and give us some guides.